# How can I conditionally wrap some HAML content in a tag?

Tags: html, haml

How can I use a condition to decide whether to output a surrounding tag in HAML? I'm trying to create the DRY version of the code below.

```
- if i_should_link 
  %a{:href => url}
   .foo
     .block
       .of  
         .code
- else
  .foo
    .block
      .of  
        .code
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how this is related to HTML if it's HAML...

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636401/haml-create-container-element-only-if-condition-is-true

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use a partial.

**foo.html.haml**

```
- if i_should_link
  %a{:href => url}
    = render 'bar'
- else
  = render 'bar'
```

**_bar.html.haml**

```
.foo
  .block
    .of
      .code
```

**Edit:** Or you could use content for, I guess this is better because it keeps it all in the same file.

```
- if i_should_link
  %a{:href => url}
    = yield :foobar
- else
  = yield :foobar

- content_for :foobar do
  .foo
    .block
      .of
        .code
```

Comment: the content_for approach is pretty good. thanks, odin. i'll see if any other solutions come in and let you know.

Comment: ..and he never let me know :-(

Comment: reminding you that you still have had no answer. Can you sleep :D?

Comment: In my case I have to first provide content_for block. Defining it at the end of the file does not work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 27):

I think odin's suggestion to use a partial is probably the best in most situations.

However, as an alternate solution, I found [a thread](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/haml@googlegroups.com/2009-06/msg00187.html) where Nathan Weizenbaum suggested defining this method:

```
def haml_tag_if(condition, *args, &block)
  if condition
    haml_tag *args, &block
   else
     yield
   end
end
```

Whatever is in the block would **always be rendered**, but the wrapping tag would appear or not based on the condition.

You would use it as follows:

```
- haml_tag_if(planning_to_mail?, :div, :id => 'envelope') do
   %p I'm a letter
```

If `planning_to_mail?` evaluates `true`, you'd get:

```
<div id="envelope">
  <p>I'm a letter</p>
</div>
```

If it evaluates `false`, you'd get:

```
<p>I'm a letter</p>
```

He floated the idea of adding this to `Haml::Helpers`, but that [doesn't appear to have happened yet](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html).

Comment: This has recently been added to Haml, but it isn’t yet in a release. Look out for it in Haml 4.1 or Haml 5: https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/66a8ee080a9fb82907618227e88ce5c2c969e9d1

Comment: This is a fantastic answer - six years on and still offering a great solution. For what it's worth, I've replaced haml_tag with content_tag in the helper and it works just as outlined above.

Comment: The `haml_tag_if helper` method mentionned in the comment above should be the accepted answer, many thanks!