# HAML: Create container/wrapper element only if condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Longshot, but I'm wondering if there's any way to do something like this:

```
%p # ONLY SHOW THIS IF LOCAL VARIABLE show_paras IS TRUE
  = name
```

In other words, it always shows the content inside, but it only wraps a container around it if (some-condition) is true.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237308/how-can-i-conditionally-wrap-some-haml-content-in-a-tag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use raw html, but then you'd have to have the if statement both at the beginning and end:

```
- if show_paras
  <p>
= name
- if show_paras
  </p>
```

Assuming you're doing more than just `= name`, you could use a partial:

```
- if show_paras
  %p= render "my_partial"
- else
  = render "my_partial"
```

You could also use HAML's `surround` (though this is a little messy):

```
- surround(show_paras ? "<p>" : "", show_paras ? "</p>" : "") do
  = name
```

Finally, what I would probably do is not try to omit the `p` tag at all, and just use CSS classes to set up two different `p` styles to look the way I want:

```
%p{:class => show_paras ? "with_paras" : "without_paras"}
  = name
```

Comment: Thanks, surround is the kind of thing I was looking for. Little messy as you say, but you could make it very clean with a helper function building on surround. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to wrap it in an alternative tag if the condition isn't met, using `haml_tag`:

```
- haml_tag(show_paras ? :p : :div) do
  = name
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method)

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way I can think of doing is like this:

```
= show_paras ? content_tag(:p, name) : name
```

But it's not exactly haml.

Generally markup is the for the content, so if show_paras is a more presentational tweak you should probably be using css to change the behaviour of the %p instead

Comment: True, I take your point, but in my case, it's a bit more involved as there's conditional content inside which would make it arguably a para (or section etc) in some cases, but in other cases, just a simple div/span.

Answer (score 2):

```
- haml_tag_if show_paras, :p do
  = name
```

https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/66a8ee080a9fb82907618227e88ce5c2c969e9d1

Comment: The old haml_tag_if! Nice.

Comment: what if I want to add atrributes to the container, such as an href to a link? 
Documentation did not enlighten me :/ https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag_if-instance_method