# Can Haml omit tags where the Ruby content evaluates to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

If I have a line in a Rails template that evaluates to nil, is there a way to have Haml not bother to generate output for that line rather than create an empty tag? For instance given this:

```
%h4= @my_hash[:optional]
```

...imagine that there's no data for that hash-key. I don't want to end up with:

```
<h4></h4>
```

I'd like no output at all from that line because empty tags can still affect page layout, particularly if you're using something CSS-heavy like Bootstrap.

I can write this everywhere:

```
-if @my_hash[:optional]
  %h4= @my_hash[:optional]
```

but it's long-winded and ugly.

(It seems like lots of people would want to do this, but I couldn't find any mention of either a way to do it in the Haml docs, or people on SO or elsewhere asking how it could be done. So *clearly* everybody already knows how to do it except me, right?)

---

Update: Thanks for the suggestions. The thing is, it doesn't seem to matter what you put after the equals sign here:

```
%h4= amazing_intelligent_helper_method_but_sadly_too_late()
```

because Haml has already decided to output a tag at that point, the only question is what goes in the tag? If the expression after the equals sign evaluates to nil, Haml doesn't put any content in the tag - but it still outputs the tag itself.

```
%h4= nil                   #output: <h4></h4>
%h4= ''                    #output: <h4></h4>
%h4= false                 #unexpected output: <h4>false</h4> 
%h4=                       #Haml::SyntaxError 'There's no Ruby code for = to evaluate.'
```

So at the moment, I don't have a one-line way of omitting empty tags. But surely I'm not the only one who wants to do this? When you look at some of the esoteric options Haml supports, I'd have really expected this feature to already be in there somewhere.

Comment: Using an `-if` is perfectly acceptable. It's not long-winded or ugly; Instead it's the equivalent of what you'd do in Ruby directly with a trailing "if".

Answer (score 1):

Just append the condition to the line ala Ruby statement modifiers:

```
%h4= @my_hash[:optional] if @my_hash[:optional]
```

Still long winded but at least its on one line now.

Here are some other techniques that were discussed but they're not any shorter or prettier: [HAML: Create container/wrapper element only if condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636401/haml-create-container-element-only-if-condition-is-true)

Comment: This won’t work, it will still create the empty tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 %h4= @my_hash[:optional] unless @my_hash[:optional].blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is my question I thought I'd suggest a semi-OK-ish answer I've just thought of in the hope that someone will look at it and say 'Aha! I can do better than that.'

I could put this in the view

```
!= h4_if @my_hash[:options]
```

and I throw this in my helper file:

```
TAGS_TO_DELETE_WHEN_EMPTY = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'p', 'span']

TAGS_TO_DELETE_WHEN_EMPTY.each do |tag|
  new_method_name = (tag + '_if').to_sym
  define_method new_method_name do |content = nil| 
    "<#{tag}>#{content}</#{tag}" if content
  end
end
```

then I only get an h4 tag if there's content for it. I can use these little conditional helper methods, coupled with Haml's unescaped ruby evaluator '!=', to get what I'm looking for. Downsides include: even though it's very concise in the view, and easy to extend, it doesn't look much like regular Haml. Also, I'm not 100% sure it won't upset Haml in some way if I use much of it.

Plus I'm still hoping someone will tell me there's an option in Haml to not output empty tags, because then I don't need to write any additional code at all (which is my favourite solution to problems).