# Conditional Top Level Tags HAML w/o using partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

What is an elegant way to conditionally add a higher level html element without repeating the inner contents? How can this be achieved without using partials (all content in one file)?

For example, say I have this content and I want to wrap all the content in a div based on some condition so the (img, 'some code' x 3) is not being repeated.

```
- unless p.product_url.nil?
  #myDiv
    %img{src: img_url}
    some code
    some code
    some code
- else
  %img{src: img_url}
  some code
  some code
  some code
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7240476/605707 offers a solution to this using `content_for`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I conditionally wrap some HAML content in a tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237308/how-can-i-conditionally-wrap-some-haml-content-in-a-tag)

Answer (score 2):

```
- content_for :inner_contents do
  %img{src: img_url}
  some code
  some code
  some code

- unless p.product_url.nil?
  #myDiv
    = yield :inner_contents
- else
  = yield :inner_contents
```

This is based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7240476/605707, as mentioned by Deefour.

Comment: Please note that `content_for` is built into Rails, so you probably can't do this with HAML alone.