# Can I convert this ERB to HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

Is it possible convert the ERB code below to HAML?

**ERB**

```
<div class="users">    
  <div class="row">
    <% i = 0 %>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <span><%= @user.name %></span>
      <% if i % 4 == 0 %>
        </div> <!-- Close div .row -->
        <div class="row"> <!-- Open new div .row -->
      <% end %>
      <% i += 1 %>
    <% end %>
  </div> <!-- Close div .row -->
</div> <!-- Close div .users -->
```

**RESULT** (HTML)

```
<div class="users">    
  <div class="row">
    <span>User Name 1</span>
    <span>User Name 2</span>
    <span>User Name 3</span>
    <span>User Name 4</span>
  </div> <!-- Close div .row -->
  <div class="row"> <!-- Open new div .row -->
    <span>User Name 5</span>
    <span>User Name 6</span>
    <span>User Name 7</span>
    <span>User Name 8</span>
  </div> <!-- Close div .row -->
  <div class="row"> <!-- Open new div .row -->
    <span>User Name 9</span>
    <span>User Name 10</span>
    <span>User Name 11</span>
    <span>User Name 12</span>
  </div> <!-- Close div .row -->
</div> <!-- Close div .users -->
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I conditionally wrap some HAML content in a tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237308/how-can-i-conditionally-wrap-some-haml-content-in-a-tag)

Comment: @matt, I edited the code, see now please. :)

Comment: Well the _original_ question was a duplicate, it isn’t anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to structure your data how you need to use it, using something like [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```haml
.users
  - @users.each_slice(4) do |group|
    .row
      - group.each do |user|
        %span= user.name
```

Comment: :( I was just about to post that. You were quick. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this instead:
EDIT:

```
.users
  -@users.each_slice(4) do |slice|
    .row
      -slice.each do |user|
        %span= user.name
```

Comment: You're right, I asked wrong. Look the edited code, please.

Comment: Modifying as per exact requirement. Please wait. :)