# How to render a partial containing if/ else statement in haml

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman, padrino

I have a partial similar to this:

```
/ _some_partial.md.haml

%div.container
  %div.optional-row
    = yield
```

With a view like this:

```
/ some_view.html.haml

---
layout: some_layout
---

= partial "some_partial" do
  %p Content here
...
```

However, I'd like the to render `some_partial` with the `%div.optional-row` wrapper in some places, but not others. Is this something that can be achieved with an `if/ else` statement?

I envisage the solution using `content_for` and looking something like:

```
/ _some_partial.md.haml

%div.container
  - if content_for?(:optional_row)
    %div.optional-row
      = yield :optional_row
  - else
    = yield
```

With

```
/ some_view.html.haml

---
layout: some_layout
---

- content_for :optional_row do
  = partial "some_partial" do
    %p Content here
...
```

I know this is horrendously wrong (it returns a `TypeError`), but I hope it explains my thought process.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237308/how-can-i-conditionally-wrap-some-haml-content-in-a-tag) seems to answer mine in part, but it doesn't explain how to render the partial with the `if/ else` conditions.

Ps. I'm using Middleman and so throwing in a Padrino tag

Comment: How can you yield the content for `:optional_row` in a partial when the output of the partial is part of that content for `:optional_row`?

Comment: All I know is that you can yield a block in a partial and render it on a page, as per https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1099. Literally been learning haml a week and wondering whether `if/ else` can be referenced when using the partial

Comment: Well, I think part of the problem is exactly that. It seems like it should be an infinite loop. What exact error do you get? If/else in a partial is perfectly fine so it's something else.